# How do I hide fontawesome icons when in fullscreen desktop view

Tags: css, icons, display

Currently coding a responsive navbar however 2 things are really bothering me that I can't get my head round. Any help would be appreciated:

1/ With my original logo pic I have been using, I have got the nav links to line up with it (like a sort of display inblock) but I have noticed only lines up in full screen view, as you minimize the screen the links cluster up underneath and then eventually disappear when the screen is really small and the togglebox appears. How can you fix this problem.

2/ I can’t get the icons to hide from the links in fullscreen view, yet I have done the display:none in the coding

My html code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>nav bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.CSS">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-    awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">

  <h1 class="Logo">logo</h1>

  <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-info site-nav--icon"></i>About us</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bus site-nav--icon"></i>blogger</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
   </div>

</div>

</header>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-    ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {

   $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
   $(this).toggleClass('open');

 })
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My CSS so far:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');

:root {
  --background: rgba(253, 254, 254, .85);
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2b58de;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header{
  background: var(--background);
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 92px;
}

h1{
  margin-left: 82px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
  background: #2043a9;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.site-nav--open {
   height: auto;

}

.site-nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.site-nav li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

.site-nav li:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}


.site-nav a{
  color: #b99902;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  background:#802CED;
  color: #000000;
}

.site-nav--icon{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: .75em;
  width: 1em;
  text-align:right;
  color: rgba(185,153,2,1);
}

 .menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.7em;
  right:1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background:#000000;
  height: 3px;
  width:1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before{
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after{
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before{
opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after{
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {

  .menu-toggle{
    display: none;
  }

  .site-nav{
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background:transparent;
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding-top: 2em;
  }

  .site-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border:none;

  }

  .site-nav a {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 3.5em;
  }

  .site-nav a:hover,
  .site-nav a:focus{
    background:transparent;
  }

  .site-nav--icon {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put de icon into a div block and hidden the div object.

```
<div class="boton-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
```

and the css:

```
.boton-menu{
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fa:fullscreen {
  display: none
}
```

... should do it.
At this point, unprefixed support sits at [1.99%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) while the prefixed support should be 81.71%:

```css
.fa:-webkit-full-screen {
  display: none
}
.fa:-moz-full-screen {
  display: none
}
.fa:-ms-fullscreen {
  display: none
}
.fa:fullscreen {
  display: none
}
```

However, in my Chrome (v70.0.3538.77) it doesn't seem to work.

According to [this article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/fullscreen/) Chrome v71 will support it.

[Spec here](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#:fullscreen-pseudo-class). 
Browser compat [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen#Browser_compatibility).

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {

  $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
  $(this).toggleClass('open');

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');
:root {
  --background: rgba(253, 254, 254, .85);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2b58de;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header {
  background: var(--background);
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 92px;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 82px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #2043a9;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.site-nav--open {
  height: auto;
}

.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.site-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.site-nav a {
  color: #b99902;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  background: #802CED;
  color: #000000;
}

.site-nav--icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: .75em;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  color: rgba(185, 153, 2, 1);
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.7em;
  right: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding-top: 2em;
  }
  .site-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
  }
  .site-nav a {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 3.5em;
  }
  .site-nav a:hover,
  .site-nav a:focus {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .site-nav--icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

.fa:-webkit-full-screen {
  display: none
}
.fa:-moz-full-screen {
  display: none
}
.fa:-ms-fullscreen {
  display: none
}
.fa:fullscreen {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="Logo">logo</h1>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-info site-nav--icon"></i>About us</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bus site-nav--icon"></i>blogger</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying mate, I've tried it doesn't seem to be hiding the icons in fullscreen, unless im inputting it wrong

Comment: I've just ran some tests and it doesn't seem to work as advertised yet. I've added my findings to the answer.